# Как прописать и затем вызвать свойства в MainActivity.kt на Kotlin под Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlin использует ООП. Но как прописать и затем вызвать свойства в MainActivity.kt? То есть, можно передать нарисованный textView  в переменной
val textView = findViewById  (R.id.firstTextView)
Если же нам нужно использовать это в других функциях, то мы должны объявить глобальную переменную (доступную для всего класса). Но считается ли это правильным подходом? Вот в Objective C (под iOS) выносятся в свойства во ViewController'ах. Но это другая платформа, другой язык. Как обстоят дела под Android в Kotlin'е? Только начинаю разбираться со всем этим.

Answer (score 0):

Вынести ссылку на View переменную на уровень класса - нормально. Вы один раз её проинициализируете и будет использовать несколько раз.

Если же вы каждый раз будете её инициализировать в месте использования - будут некоторые просадки по производительности, т.к. операция тяжелая. Надо, конечно, очень постараться, чтобы эту просадку заметить, однако она будет.